# How to import/link shared xCode project (and be able to edit shared project from any client)?

Tags: ios, xcode, shared, workspace

I don't want to compile shared project to any kind of library. I just want to use existing classes like they would integral part of client project.

I want to edit/develop/improve the shared project from any client project that use it.

I've ran trough google, but couldn't find the simpliest/more convenient approach.

---

More simple:

I want drag and drop shared code project, and be able to edit it anywhere. How?

Comment: You don't want to compile the "shared project" but you want to edit/develop/improve it?  You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: I'd happy to compile it along the client project, just it would integral part of it. I want to be able create new shared classes "anywhere" I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options: Use a static library, or include the source files directly in your project.

If you don't want to use a static library (which IMHO is the preferred method for iOS and integrates well with Xcode), you could just add references to the shared classes either as file references or as a folder reference.

Either way, the build toolchain will link everything together into one Mach-O binary, which is the only way to deliver code for the iOS.

Comment: I can't edit/expand static library in the client projects. Thats my only problem. It would be easier to not switching between projects. Thats all.

Comment: You can add the shared project to the client projects as any other file reference. This way the project itself will become expandable even though it is a static library at linking stage.